# How do I figure out which gem(s) caused a particular gem to be bundled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Is there a simple (Bundle?) command to determine which gem(s) caused a particular gem to be bundled and added to my Gemfile.lock?

There are [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694594/how-do-i-find-gems-that-depend-on-a-given-gem) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085301/how-to-find-out-which-gems-depdend-on-gem-x) similar questions but they only seem to address the general problem of figuring out which gems out there depend on a given gem.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213052/cant-activate-gem-how-do-i-figure-out-which-gem-has-a-dependency-on-this-one) is the closest to this one but it's overly specific and didn't get a good general answer.

Eventually I found the info I was after using `bundle viz` and eyeballing the resulting image until I found it and traced it back to its parent but it seems like something bundle should be able to tell me with a one line command.

I also tried `grep -r rest-client ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0` which kind of told me but the results were messy and also included a bunch of other gems that weren't from this particular app.

Is there a simpler way for next time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `Gemfile.lock` documents which dependencies were generated from other dependencies, it's listed in a rough tree form, but you may have to do some digging to get to the right spot.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that, think I just stoped searching a moment too early. Sure enough the gem I was after (`rest-client`) was listed a second time in the lock file, indented under the gem that depends on it (`ruby-jss`)